# How do i insert line breaks in product description with a SQL query

Tags: magento2, database, product-description

How can I replace (\n) in SQL with a Line Breaks?
i want to do it with a SQL query,

I want in table: `catalog_product_entity_text` replace the value with Line Breaks instead of (\n)

Comment: Export that table,then you can apply find and replace on notepad++.then import again after truncate that table

Answer (score 0):

you also added `</n>` tags and `</br>` tags but not break line so you use `<li>` tags same like this example:-

```
<li> your description write </li>
```

I hope this way helpful

try to this way :)

Comment: i want to do it with a SQL query. 32000 records.

Comment: Sorry, not helpful, because this is not a SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You can use following sql queries to replace `\n` with `<br>` .

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text SET value = REPLACE (value, '\\n', '<br>');
```

A general sql query to find and replace a matching character is given below:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'matching_string', 'replace_with');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we have used. Looked up the attribute_id for the short description, removed the carriage returns `\r` and replaced the new lines `\n` with `<br>`

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text SET value = REPLACE(REPLACE (value, '\n', '<br>') , '\r', '')
WHERE attribute_id = ( 
                SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "short_description" LIMIT 1 );
```